# Instagram api is not working

Tags: javascript, json, instagram-api

I have very few knowledge about using api, javascript.
(I'm a html/css coder)

I've been requested to use this API to get instagram pictures
that users posted using certain hashtag.

Here's the demo that's been shared by jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/j9ynxvox/10/

```
$(function() {
  // 「表示」を押すと、画像を取得します
  var endpoint = 'https://tagplus.jp/demo/api/json/medias';

  // ポップアップ用の関数
  var popup = function(item) {
    var $container = $('<div>', {'class': 'popup-container'});
    $('<div>', {'class': 'popup-overlay'}).appendTo($container);

    var $template = $($('#popup-template').html());
    $template.find('.popup-image').attr('src', item.images.standard_resolution);
    var userLink = 'https://instagram.com/' + item.media_user.username;
    $template.find('.user-link').attr('href', userLink);
    $template.find('.profile-picture')
             .attr('src', item.media_user.profile_picture);
    $template.find('.media-user-name').text(item.media_user.username);
    $template.appendTo($container);

    $('body').append($container);
    $container.fadeIn();
  };

  $(document).on(
    'click',
    '.popup-overlay',
    function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.popup-container').fadeOut(
        'fast',
        function() {
          $(this).remove();
        }
      );
    }
  );

  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#thumbnail').text('');
    $.get(
      endpoint,
      {count: 12},
      function(res) {
        res.data.forEach(function(item) {
          var $thumb = $('<img>', {
            'class': 'insta-thumb',
            src: item.images.thumbnail
          });
          $thumb.appendTo($('#thumbnails'));
          $thumb.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            popup(item);
          });
        });
      },
      'jsonp'
    );
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      $('.popup-container').fadeOut(
        'fast',
        function() {
          $(this).remove();
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

In my case, I've been asked to use this API address. https://tagplus.jp/plazastyle_Campaign/api/json/medias
(its called http://tagplus.jp/)

To start off, I simply copied and pasted this jsfiddle code
to my local files but it is not working when I click the button to load instagram pictures.

Here's my demo
http://1ne-studio.com/test2/sample.html
id : test
pass : ny2016

Why is it not working and how could I fix this?

Thank you for your time!
(In my case, I've been asked to use this API address. https://tagplus.jp/plazastyle_Campaign/api/json/medias)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: So it looks like your script is totally different from the one in the fiddle. Replace your script to the one from the fiddle and try again!

---

**Old answer:**

It's because you do not have jQuery!

Add this somewhere in the head and try again

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks for the reply. That was stupid of me. But I added jquery and it's still not working....

Comment: can you update the demo at http://1ne-studio.com/test2/sample.html so I can take a look?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just updated! please check!